# Book featuring a failed demon summoning

Tags: story-identification, demons

The book was probably somewhere in the 90's and featured an early chapter where a female sorceress summons a demon and is killed by it. She creates some form of protective circle or pentagram star; however she breaks this during the summoning, allowing the demon to kill her. She is thinking about it cracking her bones as she dies in the POV. i remember reading this in a book store somewhere and would love to know what it was

Comment: saw something like this in 1970s or earlier comic book format -- male sorcerer, had dragged body through pentagram so demon could get out. guy says, what do have for me and demon answers, death.

Comment: Title says it was a "failed" demon summoning, but the body says the demon appeared.

Comment: @user14111: if you summon the demon and it doesn't do what you want, even kills you, that would be failure, I think.

Comment: Doesn't fit since it's from the demon's point of view and the summoner is a man, but the start of Jonathan Stroud's The Ring of Solomon features a magician leaving his protective circle and getting eaten by the summoned djinn/demon.

Comment: interesdting ... is it a good book?